# android-actionbar change home button on click

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using the [android-actionbar](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) plugin.

I successfully added a home action with :

```
actionBar.setHomeAction(
   new IntentAction(this, 
   DisciplinesController.createIntent(this), R.drawable.back_button));
```

Now I would like to change the drawable when button is pressed ...
Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the ActionBar GitHub page
https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/issues/31

> I would suggest you to try the new version that is in the branch mimic-native-api. Then you can simply use setIcon on the action.

So clone this branch and that should have a *setIcon* method, I will try it myself a little later on.

Answer (score 0):

to have different images depending if you push a button or not, make a xml file like this in Drawable folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/menu_tools_green"/>
<item android:state_focused="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/menu_tools_green"/>
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/menu_tools_green"/>
<item android:state_focused="false"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/menu_tools_orange"/>
```

As you can see there is a pic for each state.

Regards